# Can you add a article tag to headlines?

Tags: html

I am wondering if you can add headline tags between article tags, and what are article tags, I am confused about them while using it with HTML.

Comment: If by headline, you mean heading tags, h1, h2, etc, then yes you can. See what a Google search for something like, *html5 article tag example*, will yield.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article

Comment: Your first step should certainly be to try it, test it and see how it behaves, and run it through an HTML validator.  If all of those things are successful then you've thoroughly answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

```
<article>
<h2>African Ants</h2>
<p>There are many types of ants living in Africa. <a href="african_ants.htm">[read more]</a></p>
</article>
```

Does that answer your question?